# How to use medias stored in AWS with Hybris

Tags: amazon-s3, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris project, I want to use medias which are stored in AWS S3. How can I add this media with their url's.

Normally, I can do it with AWS storage policy with uploading medias, but I don't want to upload images, I want to add media with link to AWS URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use OOTB Hybris **amazoncloud** extenstion.

This extenstion provides `MediaURLStrategy` and `MediaStorageStrategy` implementation for Amazon S3.

If you have access to Hybris Wiki you can get more details [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Using+Amazon+S3+Media+Storage+Strategy)